# Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspbian Jessie - How to run fsck at boot?

Tags: boot, raspbian-jessie, fsck

How to run fsck at boot when using Pi 3 and Raspberry Jessie? I have read some tutorial but they differ.

I have run `sudo touch /forcefsck` but what else I have to do? I know that I should set FSCKFIX=yes but what is the correct file? Some say `/lib/init/vars.sh` others `/etc/default/rcS`.

How can I verify that my settings are working? I have no visibility to screen. There is power outages so there is a high risk that file system gets corrupted.

**Edit:**

I tried two solution mentioned below.

**1)** By using `sudo shutdown -rF now` /var/log/boot.log says:

```
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[    3.679250] systemd-fsck[219]: fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
[    3.681320] systemd-fsck[219]: /dev/mmcblk0p1: 124 files, 2666/8057 clusters
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1.
         Mounting /boot...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Paths.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Created slice system-systemd\x2drfkill.slice.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Created slice system-ifup.slice.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Mounted /boot.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Remote File Systems.
         Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting LSB: Prepare console...
         Starting LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed)...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
```

**2)** By using `fsck.mode=force` and `fsck.repair=yes` in `/boot/cmdline.txt` bootlog says:

```
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Paths.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Created slice system-systemd\x2drfkill.slice.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Created slice system-ifup.slice.
[    5.749367] systemd-fsck[112]: Pass 2: Checking directory structure
[    8.673500] systemd-fsck[112]: Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
[    8.683831] systemd-fsck[112]: Pass 4: Checking reference counts
[    9.318835] systemd-fsck[112]: Pass 5: Checking group summary information
[    9.518754] systemd-fsck[112]: /dev/mmcblk0p2: 131321/956160 files (0.2% non-contiguous$
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started File System Check on Root Device.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1...
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0...
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[    9.639259] systemd-fsck[239]: fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
[    9.644216] systemd-fsck[239]: /dev/mmcblk0p1: 124 files, 2666/8057 clusters
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
         Mounting /boot...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Mounted /boot.
```

Why is the log file totally different in these two cases?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> I have run sudo touch /forcefsck but what else I have to do?

That's stuff that applies more to wheezy; jessie may (or may not) be backward compatible with it, but you might as well do it the new way:

Add the following to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
fsck.mode=force
```

**Make sure that file remains all one line.**  Parameters should be separated with spaces.

You'll probably notice `fsck.repair=yes` is already there; these are not the same thing.  From `man systemd-fsck` (these are actually parameters that are passed on by the kernel to [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), i.e., systemd):

> fsck.mode=
>
> One of "auto", "force", "skip". Controls the mode of operation. The default is "auto", and ensures that
>   file system checks are done when the file system checker deems them necessary.  "force" unconditionally
>   results in full file system checks.  "skip" skips any file system checks.
>
> fsck.repair=
>
> One of "preen", "yes", "no". Controls the mode of operation. The default is "preen", and will
>   automatically repair problems that can be safely fixed.  "yes " will answer yes to all questions by fsck
>   and "no" will answer no to all questions.

Comment: How this is different compared to `sudo shutdown -rF now`? Boot.log looks totally different.

Answer (score 4):

This what I am using on a Jessie old-stable release, at the end of the line in `cmdline.txt`:
`forcefsck`

I also have the following in `fstab`:

`/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,noatime  0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1`

Note the `1` and `2` at the end of the line

It checks and repairs the root partition (/dev/mmcblk0p2) on every boot (@JulianKnight not /dev/sda2).

What is described in the original OP still works for Wheezy on RPi:
`sudo touch /forcefsck`

@WillianPaixao after Wheezy the `-F` option of `shutdown` is no longer supported

How to force a filesystem check is (mostly) bound to the kernel version, at some point after Debian 8.0 (in 8.2?), it was changed as described in @goldilocks answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should also be able to do the following which should work for any Linux not just the Pi (obviously the device will change for different platforms, sda2 should be right for a default Pi SD card):

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda2
```

That should set a check every reboot. You can change the number to whatever you like. Use -i instead of -c if you want time-based checking. See the man page for more info.

Comment: That works for specific file systems only :(

Comment: `sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mmcblk0p2` for a Pi's SD card.

Answer (score 2):

I use `shutdown` with `-F` parameter. [[1]](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-force-fsck-on-the-next-reboot-or-boot-sequence/)

```
sudo shutdown -rF now
```

Comment: I executed the command. After reboot my syslog does not contain any info on an fsck run (raspbian stretch).

Comment: I just checked `man shutdown` on Raspbian - there's no -F option there.

Comment: [@WillianPaixao after Wheezy the -F option of shutdown is no longer supported](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88944/19949) per Paul Wratt's answer.

Comment: note that I prefer this option, as its a one off, user instanciated, unlike _all_ modern alternatives