# Booting RPi 3 from HDD corrupts ext4 partition each time

Tags: pi-3, usb, boot, hard-drive, fsck

I've successfully followed [these instructions](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md) to get a Raspberry Pi 3 to boot from a USB hard drive. Broadly speaking, it works very well.

Unfortunately, it seems that the root (ext4) partition doesn't get unmounted cleanly when I reboot (from the GUI or from the command line). This means that when it then tries to boot up, I just get a black screen.

In order to get it then to power up, I have to attach the hard drive to a laptop and `fsck` the ext4 partition. Once I've done that, I can put it back into the Pi, and it'll boot cleanly.

That's really annoying, though. How can I either

1. force it to `fsck` at boot time, or
2. make it unmount cleanly when it powers down?

I've tried various options in `cmdline.txt`, but with no success. I'm not even seeing the coloured splash screen, so I have a feeling it's not even getting as far as reading `cmdline.txt`, but it's hard to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that the root was fsck'ed during the boot process, if deemed necessary. You could verify that by checking the `/etc/fstab` file. Look for your root partition entry (line with a `/` in the second column) and verify that the sixth column is `1` and not `0`. It should look like the following line:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

If it is `0`, change it to `1` and restart your pi. If the last column is already set to `1`, then you should probably try forcing fsck at boot. Take a look at [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61723/raspberry-pi-3-and-raspbian-jessie-how-to-run-fsck-at-boot).

---

About the sixth field in fstab (from the man page):

> This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time.  The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesys-
>                 tems should have a fs_passno of 2.