# Unable to edit cronjob, /tmp is read-only

Tags: filesystem, cron, readwrite

I am trying to make my raspberry pi automatically restart every week. But I am unable to create the cronjob as I get a error message that the temporary crontab file was unable to be created.

```
/home/pi $ crontab -e
/tmp/crontab.Kd1gSa: Read-only file system
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting
```

But looking at the permissions of tmp it seems that all is in order:

```
/home/pi $ sudo ls -lsa /
total 80
 4 drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4096 Aug 29 16:51 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4096 Aug 29 16:51 ..
 4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 13 11:28 bin
 4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 13  2020 boot
 0 drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  3860 Sep 14 23:08 dev
 4 drwxr-xr-x 121 root root  4096 Sep  8 09:26 etc
 4 drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Aug 22 01:45 home
 4 drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4096 Aug 22 01:45 lib
16 drwx------   2 root root 16384 Feb 13  2020 lost+found
 4 drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Aug 29 16:14 media
 4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 13  2020 mnt
 4 drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Aug 22 01:45 opt
 0 dr-xr-xr-x 176 root root     0 Dec 31  1969 proc
 4 drwx------  10 root root  4096 Sep  8 09:24 root
 0 drwxr-xr-x  26 root root   880 Sep 18 06:02 run
 4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 13 11:30 sbin
 4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 13  2020 srv
 0 dr-xr-xr-x  12 root root     0 Dec 31  1969 sys
 4 drwxrwxrwt  18 root root  4096 Sep 19 00:00 tmp
 4 drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Aug 21 23:55 usr
 4 drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Sep  6 10:27 var
```

What could be the problem here?

---

As Seamus pointed out my file-system seems to be read-only. I used apple-pi-baker to flash this drive from a backup. I just don't have physical access to this device since its across the country atm at my university.

```
/home/pi $ mount -l -t ext4
/dev/mmcblk0p7 on / type ext4 (ro,relatime) [root]
```

I have added the fs check commands to the bootline which was in a different location than /boot

```
/home/pi $ sudo ls -lsa /media/pi/boot/cmdline.txt
1 -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 179 Dec 31  1979 /media/pi/boot/cmdline.txt

/home/pi $ sudo cat /media/pi/boot/cmdline.txt
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes fsck.mode=force rw rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

I think my raspberry pi is able to boot to desktop due to the `rw` in my cmdline. B/c without it I get read-only file system errors at boot. But I also this this might be leaving parts of the filesystem to be read-only?

```
/home/pi $ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        26G   21G  4.1G  84% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G   52M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  370M  3.5G  10% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p6  253M   55M  198M  22% /media/pi/boot
/dev/mmcblk0p1  2.4G  2.3G   87M  97% /tmp/tmp.5LW77DmOAt
```

[image: gparted output]

Comment: Also make sure you have enabled writing to your drive using `rw` in an elevated command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First problem:

Your `/tmp` permissions are in order - that's not the problem.

First guess is that your filesystem is broken. The solution is to re-flash your SD card (You ***do*** have a backup, right?).

You can also check to make sure you've not somehow inadvertently mounted your filesystem as `ro`:

```bsh
$ mount -l -t ext4
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
```

If you get an output that's different from this (on `/dev/mmcblk0p2`), then you may have other issues. You can edit your question to share this & we'll have a look.

If you don't have a backup, or if you want to gain some experience, you can attempt to repair your filesystem with `fsck`. However, the **thing** with `fsck` is that it can only be run on an **unmounted** file system, so you will need to run it during the boot process - before `/` is mounted. There are a couple of ways to do this, but the *preferred* method for RPi (and all other distros that use `systemd`) is to add the following kernel boot parameters to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
fsck.mode=force
fsck.repair=yes
```

There's already at least two good answers here on how to do this, so [check this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116571/83790) or [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61739/83790) if you decide to do this.

## Second problem

And one other thing to do once your filesystem issue is sorted:

1. `reboot` requires `root` privileges; i.e. `sudo reboot`
2. you **should not** use `sudo` in a `crontab` for user `pi`
3. instead, create a crontab for `root`:

```bsh
sudo crontab -e 

# in your crontab editor, add this line to run every Sunday at 02:00:

`0 2 * * MON reboot`

# save & close editor
```

See `man 5 crontab` & the ["crontab guru"](https://crontab.guru/) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have added the additional information. This device was restored from a backup but I currently don't have physical access to the pi. :(

Comment: I am a bit confused on how to create the root crontab. Would it be `sudo crontab -u root -e` or `crontab -e -u root`? Or do you normally go about it a different way?

Comment: @GabrielFair: `sudo crontab -e` will do it. And since it runs with `root` privileges, you don't need to use `sudo`. Using `sudo` in a `cron` job would be problematic b/c `sudo` would have to authenticate the `cron` user & there's no good way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The mode of /tmp is supposed to be 1777.

`sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`

The 777 part means anyone can read, write or search the directory.
The 1 part means only the owner of each file in the directory is allowed to delete it.